# Which seforim did you use when learning for Rabbinic Semicha

Tags: jewish-books, shulchan-aruch, semicha

Which sforim and topics are commonly learned by students who are studying to receive Rabbinic ordination?

ie: Yoreh De'ah Melicha - Tur V'Shulchan Aruch

Different groups within Orthodox Judaism require different levels of in depth study in Halacha. The question will show readers a broad spectrum of what kind of learning goes into different Semicha programs.

Comment: @ShmuelBrin http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/304/what-jewish-print-periodicals-do-you-read#comment714_304

Comment: @ه ه I took this to be an advice question - If I'm considering studying for Semichah, which Sefarim do I need to purchase or borrow?

Comment: there is no set of "required texts", nor can there be an exhaustive list of every text which was used in a particular program, and I don't think that hearing what anyone used in one program has any bearing on any other. If someone were to ask an English MA student "what books did you read" the student would say "the particular books are not what matters." It seems like a non-question or at least it has no  real answer. Maybe a question like "what are the required texts for the _____ smicha program" is answerable, but maybe not.

Comment: @dan I think you are looking to much into it to find a problem. There are a basic level of standard seforim like Tur V'Shulchan Aruch and many commentaries from Achronim. You are right that maybe "Kosher in the Kitchen" published by artscroll might not be appropriate for the list but then is it really a problem?

Comment: so i was told before i started that i had to have an tur and a shulchan aruch constantly handy, and a rambam. but that doesn't cover what texts i used (no shas or tanach was listed...) or how i used them, or what achronim i relied on or had to learn. what does it really tell? just what i went out and bought before i started.

Comment: What are you trying to get at here? If anyone is interested in having questions about a Semicha program then finding information about which seforim is useful. It is also interesting to find out which seforim different groups focus on ie: Litvish, Sephardic, Chassidic, Modern Orthodox, etc. It is a fact per the StackXchange TOS that different groups have standards.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### In the Chabad world, it depends on the program.

**All learn**

- Basar Bechalav
- Taaroves (or Taaruvos)
- Parts of Melicha

**Some learn**

- Full Melicha
- Koshering Vessels
- Shabbos
- Birchos Hanehenin
- Pas Akum/Bishul Akum/Chalav Akum

### Useful Materials

Yoreh De'ah -

- Gemara/Rashi
- Tur/Beis Yosef/some Bachs
- Shulchan Aruch/Shach/Taz (some Pri Megadims, mostly brought down in Shiur)
- Shaarei Yoreh Deyah - A summary of the "Shach"s and "Taz"es (similar to
- Maareches Hashulchan
- Badei Hashulchan (brought down in shiurim)
- Aruch Hashulchan (brought down in shiurim)
- Piskei Dinim of the Alter Rebbe on Yoreh Deah (it's a blue sefer which extrapolates R' Shneur Zalman of Liadi's shittos in Yoreh Deah from Hilchos Pesach (and other sources).

Shabbos - Due to the fact that I studies in Lubavitch, the material here is geared to the "Chabad" circle.

- Alter Rebbe's Shulchan Aruch.
- Ktzos Hashulchan
- Sefer Shabbos Kehalacha (brought down in shiurim)

---

### [Rabbanut](http://www.rabanut.gov.il/vf/ib_items/240/bhinot.pdf) gets tested on:

- Shabbos - 242-344 (one must learn simanim 253-259, 279, 302, 307-311, 313-322, 325, 328-331, 337, 340 in depth).
- Issur Veheter - Mlicha, Basar Bechalav, Taaroves, Bishul Akum, siman 212, 213, 220, 221.
- Nidda
- Mikvaos
- Chuppa V'Kidushin - Even Haezer 1, 2, 4, 6, 9, 13, 26, 27, 34, 42, 52:1, 61, 62, 64, 66, 126:2 - 126:7 and Choshen Mishpat 33-34
- Semachot - Yoreh Deah siman 340-403

**Useful Materials:**

See [Smicha.co.il](http://www.smicha.co.il/sfarim.php?it=1)

Comment: No Bet Yosef??`

Comment: I consider it included in the Tur (like the Shach and Taz is included in the Shulchan Aruch).

Comment: @ه ه Beith Yosef is incredibly useful, if only to help understand where the Shulhan 'Aruch is coming from.

Comment: @SethJ It's also a useful (rough) Maarei Mkomos list

Comment: @ShmuelBrin, As the question is asking for the Sefarim that "most people" studied, I don't think Sifrei Lubavitch or Sifrei Hasiduth in general fit the bill. If you are just compiling a personal list, sure. But if you are listing what someone will need when embarking on the path to Semichah, I'd make it a footnote or clearly separate it as its own category for Hasidim.

Comment: @ShmuelBrin Totally.

Comment: And I didn't mean that it wasn't useful beyond that. I meant "if only" in the sense of "If you get nothing else out of it, for some unfathomable reason, you will at least get where he's coming from in ShU"'A."

Comment: The Alter Rebbe's Shuchlan Aruch is just as valid as Mishneh Berurah and Aruch HaShulchan.

Comment: @ShmuelBrin I understand. Shulchan Aruch HaRav was good enough for it to be quoted by the Chofetz Chaim but not for todays generation v'dal.

Comment: @SethJ The shulchan aruch isn't a sefer halacha, its a sum-up of the Bet Yosef. See its intro.

Comment: @mochinrechavim I also understand. The Rambam was good enough to be quoted by the Shulchan Aruch, but not for today's generation.

Comment: @هه The Shulchan Aruch in the end is a sefer halacha hence why many such as the Maharal and the Mahrasha were not happy that it was published.

Comment: @DoubleAA Seem good enough for the Chassidic world as we mark 30 years of Siyum HaRambam. Do the litvish skip over the parts where the M.B. quotes the S.A. HaRav? :)

Comment: @mochinrechavim AFAIK no they don't. My point is not that it isn't an important work; it's that for some people it has been supplanted as the most recent work. The fact that the chafetz chayim quoted it doesn't prove it is still useful as a final authority. (It doesn't prove otherwise either.)

Comment: @mochinrechavim Hacham Ovadia Yosef quotes Shulchan Aruch HaRav all the time in his teshuvot. It isn't an exclusively hassidic work.

Comment: @هه I am not familiar with any Sephardic Halachic Responsa. I also didn't ever say anything about exclusivity. In fact your statement further proves my point of the validity of the Alter Rebbe's S.A. among Halachic Giants.

Comment: what about melicha and shechita?

Comment: @Menachem not everyone does mlicha, and I've never heard of anyone that requires Shechita.

Comment: around 2000, one of the portions of Labkovski's Smicha was Trefos (not Shechita, my mistake). I don't know if that's still the case today. Some learned Birchat Hanehenin instead.

Comment: @Menachem I *heard* that R' Osdoba now tests on treifos, but I haven't heard of anyone who received smicha from him. Now, I hear that everyone is doing birchas hanehenin.

Comment: @Menachem ^ I heard that Labkovsky tests birchas hanehenin.

Answer (score 5):

The Kaf Hachaim, Dagul Marvava(Noda B'Yeuda) , Pischei Tshuva, Biur HaGra, Beir Heitev, They Really explain the Psak Halacha clearly and sometimes add very interesting things.

Answer (score 5):

I would say that the goal should be to learn from the Gemara and Rishonim upwards- ie/ if doing aveilut, start with Moed Katan, if learning kashrut, start with Chullin, etc. This is the approach which I believe the Rabbanut uses. I am familiar with the derech halimud of the Institute for Traditional Judaism in Teaneck. They learn Perakim Gid haNasheh v' Kol haBasar from Masechet Chullin, Issur v' Heter (Melicha, Basar v'Chalav, Taaruvot) from the Gemara, Rishonim, Shulchan Aruch, and Nosei Keilim, and with special emphasis on the Tur and Torat HaBayit of the Rashba. Niddah is learned from the Rishonim and Masekhet Niddah, with the Baalei haNefesh of the Raavad, Torat haBayit of the Rashba, Tur, Shulchan Aruch, and Nosei Keilim. Hilkhot Shabbat is learned from Shulchan Aruch, Chayyei Adam, Mishnah Berurah, and Shemirat Shabbat keHilkhata. Hilkhot Geirut is learned from the Gemara, Shulchan Aruch, Nosei Keilim, and with an emphasis on the teshuvot of Reb Moshe, Melamed LeHoil, Rambam, and R' Benzion Uziel, and the remainder of Orach Chaim is learned with Mishnah Berurah and Aruch haShulchan (seder hayom, tefilla, chagim, taaniyot, etc.) See here: http://www.themetivta.org/curriculum

Comment: I heard that Maseches Nidda has very little to do with modern day Halachos (in contrast to Tuma/Tahara)