# What is the typical course for dayanut?

Tags: halacha, product-recommendation, jewish-books, semicha

Related to this [discussion](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/15796/which-seforim-did-you-use-when-learning-for-rabbinic-semicha) on semicha (issur v'heter), what is the syllabus usually used for Dayanut? This used to be available on the Montefiore yeshiva website, but I can't find it any longer.

Any particular review books, as per discussion on semikha?

Comment: Try to make this question freestanding, so that no one has to go to the other to ascertain your intent. Thus, instead of "Any particular review books, as per discussion on semikha?" use perhaps "Any particular review books [with whatever properties you seek, as discussed in the other question]?".

Answer (score 3):

This is pirchei Shoshanim's Dayanus course http://www.shulchanaruch.com/wp/courses/dayanus-course/

Comment: As of Jan 2019 the link is dead